# Can we using Nullable<DateTime> as a DependencyProperty in XAML for Metro-style apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to use a `DateTime?` property as a DependencyProperty so that I can bind it in XAML in a Metro-style app.

However, when the app runs (in debug mode), I get a binding error, and the date does not show up in my control:

> Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'System.DateTime,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' to type 'DateTime>';
>   BindingExpression: Path='Model.Date'
>   DataItem='MyProject.Common.ViewModel.TransactionViewModel, MyProject,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element
>   is 'MyProject.Controls.DatePicker' (Name='null'); target property is
>   'SelectedValue' (type 'DateTime>').

The dependency property is defined as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", 
                                typeof (System.Nullable<System.DateTime>),
                                typeof(DatePicker),
                                PropertyMetadata.Create(default(DateTime?)));
```

In the XAML page, it is used as:

```
<local:DatePicker  
   Margin="0,10" 
   SelectedValue="{Binding Model.Date, Mode=TwoWay}" 
   FontSize="21.333"/>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this and get the date showing in the control and bind both ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is DatePicker expects `DateTime` type not `DateTime?` which is a syntactic sugar for Nullable. There is no implicit conversion from `DateTime?` to `DateTime`. Write your own [IValueConverter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx). You can step yourself back and ask the question: Do you need DateTime? Can you represent a non-existing date as 00/00/00?

Another option is to convert it before binding e.g.

```
DateTime dateTime = nullDateTime ?? new DateTime(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Cool - that worked :). I'm now using a DateTime instead of DateTime? and the control and binding work.